# UPDATE is not allowed because the statement updates view "table_name" which participates in a join and has an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am getting the following error while executing the following query in an Stored Procedure. Could anyone help in finding the fault?

> UPDATE is not allowed because the statement updates view "sup_item" which participates in a join and has an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger.

```
UPDATE si
SET 
    name = mc.name,
    sup_item_cat_id = mc.res_sup_item_cat_id,
    xf_value = mc.xf_value,
    ava_start_date = mc.ava_start_date,
    ava_end_date = mc.ava_end_date,
    status_code = mc.status_code,
    last_mod_us_id = CASE WHEN mc.last_mod_us_id = 42 THEN @posting_us_id 
                     ELSE mc.last_mod_us_id END,
    last_mod_tsp = CURRENT_tsp
FROM sup_item AS si
    JOIN merch_cat_imp_sup_item AS mc
        ON mc.sup_id = si.sup_id
        AND mc.res_sup_item_id = si.sup_item_id
        AND mc.cat_imp_event_id = @cat_imp_event_id
        AND mc.accept_flag = 'y'
WHERE si.shi_flag = 'n'
```

I found the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

> A view with an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger cannot be a target of an
>   UPDATE with a FROM clause.

So, I have to rewrite the UPDATE statement (it still can be in a procedure) to NOT use `sup_item` (which is a view), but keep the underlying table(s) as needed.

Could someone please rewrite it, if anyone knows what to do?

Comment: Please post the code behind the SUP_ITEM view so we can help you better.

Comment: It is not possible to write a query using the tables underlying view sup_item without actually knowing what those tables are or how they are used within the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not within your query.  As per comments on your question, the entity you are updating [sup_item], isn't actually a table, it's a view.  That view has an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on it.

Are you able to post the SQL for the View and for the Trigger(s)?

Comment: But an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger is there TO ALLOW UPDATES TO THE VIEW. That's the whole point of an INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER. This error message (which I'm currently getting) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @pmbAustin You realise this is over Eight years ago. Post a new question, with full details, rather  than a comment on an answer older than my son?  (SOME updates are allowed on views, but not all...)

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?
This literally is incorrect.

Answer (score 23):

You can use MERGE to achieve this.  Try:

```
MERGE INTO  sup_item  si
USING merch_cat_imp_sup_item AS mc
        ON mc.sup_id = si.sup_id
        AND mc.res_sup_item_id = si.sup_item_id
        AND mc.cat_imp_event_id = @cat_imp_event_id
        AND mc.accept_flag = 'y'
        AND si.shi_flag = 'n'
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE
SET 
    name = mc.name,
    sup_item_cat_id = mc.res_sup_item_cat_id,
    xf_value = mc.xf_value,
    ava_start_date = mc.ava_start_date,
    ava_end_date = mc.ava_end_date,
    status_code = mc.status_code,
    last_mod_us_id = CASE WHEN mc.last_mod_us_id = 42 THEN @posting_us_id 
                     ELSE mc.last_mod_us_id END,
    last_mod_tsp = CURRENT_tsp
```

Comment: This works well for me.  Slightly confused as to why it would though - I'd welcome any suggestions as to why a merge works where a typical update doesn't.

Comment: Great! saved my day!

Comment: This is the correct answer -- thank you for sharing. I don't get why it works but it does.  Great solution!

Comment: @LeoGurdian only Microsoft guys would know why they do not allow an `UPDATE` statement in a view when it is using a `JOIN` clause.

Comment: @Cleptus I never had to use MERGE until now.

Comment: The MERGE should terminate with a semicolon, otherwise an error will be thrown.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: This works and should be the accepted solution.
The accepted answer is both incorrect and trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I would also be interested, because I have a stored procedure in a database that I have inherited which tries to do this.  It won't let me create the sproc in SQL 2014, but the fact that it is there in the sproc indicates to me that an earlier version of SQL server must have allowed this.

Comment: I have this exact same scenario. Worked in prior versions of SQL Server, but not in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in earlier versions your procedure operated on a table, which was later replaced by a view.

You should replace your "update from" syntax by standard ANSI syntax of update.

Comment: And what would 'standard ANSI syntax' look like in this situation?

Comment: This answer is more relevant that it seems. Today I had the same error in SQL Server 2008, and the reason is because a table was replaced by a view with an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger. Unfortunately an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger only works if the UPDATE statement that updates the view doesn't have a FROM clause. This is described in the original reference to the Microsoft library in the question. Also I think the above comment about the "update from" syntax refers to the fact that UPDATE FROM isn't standard ANSI SQL (even though it's useful!)

Comment: @Ubercoder So explain how one is to update a view that is updatable (because of the INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger) when one needs to update a subset of rows by joining with another table?  Because the updated value COMES from another table? Again, this restriction makes zero sense to me.